# V8 How to convert v8::Persistent<v8::Primitive> to v8::Primitive?

Tags: v8

I'm using V8 javascript engine and storing some values in a C++ object using this:

```
v8::Persistent<v8::Primitive>  m_Value;
```

I want to use the saved value to set another Primitive and return like this:

```
bool 
MyClass::Convert(v8::Primitive& oValue)
{
   oValue.Clear();  //<--Is Not a value method for Primitive. How can I clear it or set it to Null or Undefined?
   oValue= m_Value;
}
```

This 2nd line results in a compiler error:
binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'v8::Persistent' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

How do I get the Primitive value back out of the Persistent?
I've tried to dereference m_Value.  No luck.
This HAS to be simple...

Answer (score 1):

Since V8 primitives are garbage-collected, you must access them through handles. In your code, `m_Value` is a handle, but your method's output should also be a handle:

```
bool
MyClass::Convert(Handle<Primitive>& oValue)
{
    oValue = Local<Primitive>::New(m_Value);
    return true;
}
```

Also, depending on your scenario, you might want to create two methods, one that explicitly outputs a local handle and another that outputs a persistent handle. Or you could use a method template.